# Summarize based on multiple filters

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a dataframe

```
x = data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2), y = c(1, 2, 2, 2))
```

I want to use `dplyr` to determine the fraction of each value of `y` grouped by `x`.

So the answer should be

```
x y1 y2
1 .5 .5
2 0  1
```

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with dplyr's `count()`, a `group_by()`/`mutate()`, and tidyr's `spread()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  count(x, y = paste0("y", y)) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(n = n / sum(n)) %>%
  spread(y, n, fill = 0)
```